# vagrant up vboxmanage verr_path_not_found when default vb machine folder on f:

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

Windows 10

Vagrant file is located on Drive E:\Vagrant\ubuntu-trusty-vb

Virtualbox machine folder F:

When vagrant up runs the HardDisk entry in the.vbox files does not get changed to the correct  directory  and is  `f:\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1465748344502_5020`  instead of the one actually created `F:\ubuntu-trusty-vb_default_1465748361721_37792`

```
<HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{e1fce00d-2c78-4d36-9bff-5fcb08ff1b32}" location="f://ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1465855041577_18173/box-disk1.vmdk" format="VMDK" type="Normal"/>
</HardDisks>

E:\Vagrant\ubuntu-trusty-vb>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ubuntu-trusty-vb_default_1465855058236_73527
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "197fba85-e448-449d-a7d3-14565879a8e4", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not open the medium 'f:\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1465855041577_18173\box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage.exe: error: VD: error VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND opening image file 'f:\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1465855041577_18173\box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
```

Is this a bug or is there something I can change in the vagrantfile or configuration?

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem!!   My development files are all on d: but I don't have enough space on D: for the virtual machine, so I set the default location in VirtualBox to be f: and I get exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this post is quite old but I have recently got this error and it was solved using a workaround. You have to end up set `--uartmode1` to `disconnected` like following in Vagrant config file:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 4096
        v.cpus = 4
        v.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]
end
```

Greetings, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue. Strange that it hasn't been fixed in these two years.

Essentially, the fix is to apply the patch mention here:
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8275#issuecomment-291031171

The problem - the patch refers to a code fragment in version_5_1.rb file but that code has been moved to version_5_0.rb. This means, you cannot apply the patch as is. In the future, it might change even more, and thus my instructions may become obsolete...

I was too lazy to edit the patch and learn how to apply it properly, so I ended up applying the changes one by one to the relevant files, as described in the patch. On Windows, I had to also change file permissions to give Modify permissions to computer users.

So, the steps are as follows:

1. open the path where Vagrant Ruby files were installed. For example, `C:\Program Files\Vagrant\embedded\gems\2.1.2\gems\vagrant-2.1.2\plugins\providers\virtualbox`
2. open subfolder `action` and in give Modify permissions to Users group on files `import.rb` and `set_name.rb` (permissions can be edited as usual through context menu, in Properties, tab Security, button Edit.., select Users and check the checkbox under Allow for Modify option)
3. open file `import.rb` and replace line

   ```
   id = env[:machine].provider.driver.import(ovf_file) do |progress|
   ```

   with

   ```
   id = env[:machine].provider.driver.import(ovf_file,env) do |progress|
   ```

   There should be just one line to replace.
4. open file `set_name.rb` and find `def call(env)` and add the following lines right under it:

   ```
         return @app.call(env)
   ```
5. open subfolder `driver` and in give Modify permissions to Users group on file `version_5_0.rb`
6. open file `version_5_0.rb` and replace line

   ```
   def import(ovf)
   ```

   with

   ```
   def import(ovf,env)
   ```
7. in the same file `version_5_0.rb` replace line

   ```
   specified_name = "#{suggested_name}_#{(Time.now.to_f * 1000.0).to_i}_#{rand(100000)}"
   ```

   with the following fragment

   ```
     name = env[:machine].provider_config.name
     # If no name was manually set, then use a default
     if !name
       prefix = "#{env[:root_path].basename.to_s}_#{env[:machine].name}"
       prefix.gsub!(/[^-a-z0-9_]/i, "")

       # milliseconds + random number suffix to allow for simultaneous
       # `vagrant up` of the same box in different dirs
       name = prefix + "_#{(Time.now.to_f * 1000.0).to_i}_#{rand(100000)}"
     end

     specified_name = "#{name}_#{(Time.now.to_f * 1000.0).to_i}_#{rand(100000)}"
   ```
8. find and delete the broken virtual machine and all of its files on the other disk, and also from `.vagrant\machines` folder where you launched `vagrant up` command. Then run `vagrant up` again.

Now the virtual machine should be created with a proper name and should work normally.